# Access multiple files from multiple file inputs using $_FILES after using FormData (And add to ACF data on WP Backend)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Using Wordpress, I'm attempting to access files from one out of two file inputs using $_FILES but running into some problems:

To outline - I'm using a front-end form that has two file fields, both of which accept multiple files:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="my_name">
    <input type="file" name="reference_images[]" multiple>
    <input type="file" name="photo_of_area[]" multiple>
</form>
```

The file inputs will be taking images, and I need to upload images from "reference_images" to one repeater field, ad "photo_of_area" to another repeater field. This form is posted via AJAX using FormData - the functions for this are below:

```
function saveForm(varform) {
    blockUI();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.ajaxObject.ajaxUrl,
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: varform,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: onSuccesPing(),
        crossDomain:true,
    });
}

jQuery('#form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submitting as normal
    var formData = new FormData(jQuery('#form')[0]);
    formData.append("action", "messaging_post");       
    saveForm(formData);
});
```

I then have a function handle the messaging_post action which is below, this creates a new post with the form data, and loops over the attached images and injects them to my ACF repeater:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_messaging_post', 'messaging_post' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_messaging_post', 'messaging_post');
function messaging_post(){
    if(isset($_POST['my_name'])) {
        $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['my_name']);
        $new_post = array(
            'ID' => '',
            'post_type' => 'quote_requests',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_title' => $title, 
            'post_content' => '',
        );        
        
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
        $post = get_post($post_id);

        update_field('name', $name, $post_id); // Updates the ACF text field 'name' for the inserted post


        // Works, but uploads files from BOTH file inputs to the single ACF repeater:
        foreach($_FILES as $value){
            for ($i=0; $i <count($value['name']); $i++) { 
                $errors= array();
                $file_name = $value['name'][$i];
                $file_size = $value['size'][$i];
                $file_tmp = $value['tmp_name'][$i];
                $file_type = $value['type'][$i];
                $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$value['name'][$i])));
                
                if(empty($errors)==true) {
                    $wordpress_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
                    $profilepicture = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'].'/';
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $profilepicture.$file_name);
                } else{
                    print_r($errors);
                }
                $file_name_and_location = $profilepicture.$file_name;
                $file_title_for_media_library = $value['name'][$i];
                $fildename = $value['name'][$i];
                $arr_file_type     = wp_check_filetype(basename($fildename));
                $uploaded_file_type = $arr_file_type['type'];
                $attachment = array(
                    'post_mime_type' => $uploaded_file_type,
                    'post_title' => addslashes($file_title_for_media_library),
                    'post_content' =>  $fildename,
                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                    'post_parent' =>  0,
                    'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
                );        
                wp_read_image_metadata( $file_name_and_location );
                $attach_id     = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_name_and_location,true,false);         
                $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$file_name_and_location );
                wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
                $images[]= array("image" => $attach_id);
            }
        }
        update_field('photo_area', $images, $post_id);
    }
}
```

The above works, and populates the created post with the name from the form, but this attaches files from BOTH the reference_images and photo_of_area to the photo_area ACF repeater.

When trying to access $_FILES using a function such as the following:

```
foreach($_FILES["photo_of_area"] as $value){
    for ($i=0; $i <count($value['name']); $i++) { 
        $errors= array();
        $file_name = $value['name'][$i];
        $file_size = $value['size'][$i];
        $file_tmp = $value['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_type = $value['type'][$i];
        $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$value['name'][$i])));
        
        if(empty($errors)==true) {
            $wordpress_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $profilepicture = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'].'/';
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $profilepicture.$file_name);
        } else{
            print_r($errors);
        }
        $file_name_and_location = $profilepicture.$file_name;
        $file_title_for_media_library = $value['name'][$i];
        $fildename = $value['name'][$i];
        $arr_file_type     = wp_check_filetype(basename($fildename));
        $uploaded_file_type = $arr_file_type['type'];
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $uploaded_file_type,
            'post_title' => addslashes($file_title_for_media_library),
            'post_content' =>  $fildename,
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'post_parent' =>  0,
            'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
        );        
        wp_read_image_metadata( $file_name_and_location );
        $attach_id     = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_name_and_location,true,false);         
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$file_name_and_location );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
        $images[]= array("image" => $attach_id);
    }
}
update_field('photo_area', $images, $post);
```

This doesn't seem to work and returns nothing.

I'm assuming that after going through FormData(), the files are now not accessible on the normal $_FILES['name_of_input'], and should rather have something else done with them?

I've also tried just appending the images to the FormData, but seemed to be having the same issue.

Would anyone be able to shed some light on how I could access $_FILES["photo_of_area"], and also $_FILES["reference_images"] independently of each other after being passed through FormData()? Or any alternative ways that I should look at to achieve the desired behaviour.

Ideally, I need to access images from each file input respectively.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to achieve this by changing my loop over the $_FILES array as such:

```
$photo_of_area = $_FILES["photo_of_area"]; 
foreach ($photo_of_area['name'] as $key => $value) {
    $errors     = array();

    $file_name  = $photo_of_area['name'][$key];
    $file_size  = $photo_of_area['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp   = $photo_of_area['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type  = $photo_of_area['type'][$key];
    $file_ext   = strtolower(end(explode('.',$photo_of_area['name'][$key])));


    if (empty($errors) == true) {
        $wordpress_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $upload_dir_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'].'/';
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $upload_dir_path.$file_name);
    } else {
        print_r($errors);
    }


    $file_name_and_location         = $upload_dir_path.$file_name;
    $file_title_for_media_library   = $photo_of_area['name'][$key];
    $fildename                      = $photo_of_area['name'][$key];
    $arr_file_type                  = wp_check_filetype(basename($fildename));
    $uploaded_file_type             = $arr_file_type['type'];


    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type'    => $uploaded_file_type,
        'post_title'        => addslashes($file_title_for_media_library),
        'post_content'      =>  $fildename,
        'post_status'       => 'inherit',
        'post_parent'       =>  0,
        'post_author'       => get_current_user_id(),
    );    

    wp_read_image_metadata( $file_name_and_location );
    $attach_id          = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_name_and_location,true,false);         
    $attach_data        = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$file_name_and_location );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    $area_photos_array[]           = array("image" => $attach_id);
}

update_field('photo_area', $area_photos_array, $post_id);
```

This successfully injects each image uploaded to a new row of the photo_area repeater inside the current post specified by $post_id.